# Reverse for url with arguments '('',)' not found, but only on a certain machine

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I deployed using Gunicorn and Nginx, and am seeing this error in one machine that's using my app, but not in the rest, so I'm starting to think it is an issue on the machine the error is displaying but not in the app. When doing the exact same actions to replicate the error in other machines, the app works just fine.

The template form that causes the error:

```
            <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_quantity"></label>
                    <input data-toggle="touchspin" type="number" value="1" required id="id_quantity" name="quantity" data-bts-button-down-class="btn btn-danger" data-bts-button-up-class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="hidden" name="override" value="False" id="id_override">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
                    <i class="uil-plus-circle"></i>
                    Add to order
                </button>
            </form>
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'cart'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    path('add/<int:product_id>', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
    path('remove/<int:product_id>', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
    path('clear/', views.cart_clear, name='cart_clear'),
]
```

views.py:

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'],              override_quantity=cd['override'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

Again, in other machines it is working just fine.

Comment: How does the view looks like that renders the template?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a product with an empty id field causing that error seeing as the argument passed to the url is empty when it should be a number. You can try inspecting the products from the admin dashboard.

Comment: I have cheched the Admin Dashboard and all the products have proper ids, plus, like I said, in othe rmachines it works fine under the exact conditions. It's only on one machine that the error is displayed.

Comment: Then the view is probably returning "no product". Can you please add the code for the template causing the error

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have created an id field for yourself. Check if a product has its id field set to empty or other symbols.

Comment: No. The id field is created by the database automatically for each product. It's not created manually in the model.

Comment: What are the specifications for the machine that brings up this error?

Comment: Intel i5-8350, 8GB RAM Windows 10. I opened it from a MacBook and it worked perfectly. It is just that machine that fails.